# How do I assign an IBAction to a second ViewController?

Tags: xcode

I have this project with two ViewControllers. It´s very simple. In the second window I only want a button to perform an action (link to iTunes store). I´m adding the code to my .h and .m files, but it´s not possible to link the actions to my button in the second window. But I can into the first one… I swear that I surfed and searched but I can´t find an answer to something like this. Should be easy, shouldn´t it? Thanx everybody!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create an `IBAction` in one ViewController, it will not be visible from the other. This is just the nature of ViewControllers. If you want to, you can make the second class inherit the methods and variables form the other. You can do this by replacing

```
@interface SecondViewController: UIViewController {
```

with

```
@interface SecondViewController: FirstViewController {
```

in SecondViewController.h

(and if you get an error, add `#import "FirstViewController.h"` at the very top of the class)

Comment: Thanks a lot for fast answer… Sorry for my ignorance, should I create one new .h and one new .m files? And then write my code there? How does the second viewcontroller at storyboard relates to these new files?

Comment: You should be able to use the same .h and .m files and still get it to work. I've never personally bothered to use storyboard, but I think I get what you're trying to say.

Each ViewController acts independently of the other, with its own set of files. With the modified code above, the second class imports all of the variables and methods (including the IBAction you mentioned) into its own set of files, so you can then use them in the second class's storyboard. I hope this helped answer your question.

Comment: So depressing… I can´t make it work. Added a new set of files. Added your code, modified it, tried different options… Still nothing. Thanks a lot for your interest… I don´t get how to make my second window to recognize my new set of files. I mean, no error displayed, but IBActions are still not available for my new viecontroller.

Comment: Well… I found it myself… I was so sure that it should be easy… In the navigation bar (the bar down the screenviewer) you have this red cube called “First Responder”, when you press that button, in the connection inspector you will see a list of the IBActions, and then you can CTRL+DRAG to the secon ViewController´s button and make it work. Thanks to you all!!!

Comment: I assume you're doing an iOS app, correct? If so, you should always be linking to an entry called "File's Owner." It should be the same procedure of CTRL-dragging, but just check to see if that would work instead of using First Responder.